# Writing functions in R - calling external functions from libraries

Tags: function, r, inherited

So I am trying to take a bit of code that I use for interactive selection and identification.  It works outside of a function but gives an error when I try to run it as a stand alone function.

```
my.identify <- function(data)
  {
    # allows you to create a polygon by clicking on map 
   region = locator(type = "o")  
   n = length(region$x)
   p = Polygon(cbind(region$x, region$y)[c(1:n,1),])
   ps = Polygons(list(p), ID="region")
   sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

   # returns all data that overlaps new polygon sps
   a=data[!is.na(overlay(data,sps)),]    # here is the problem
   return(a)
  }
```

Basically it doesn't want to run the overlay function (function of the **sp** package).  The error report is that I can't run the inherited functions??

> Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function "overlay", for signature "matrix",
>   "SpatialPolygons"

Any ideas??? I'm new to function writing... so hopefully it will be easy.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, and fwiw ?over is recommended rather than overlay()

Comment: and this works fine for me - I don't see the error you report so please update the question with full details.  I think it comes down to what you want to overlay with what - is "data" intended to be points, or could it be poylgons (or lines)?  if not just points you will want package rgeos

Comment: library(rgdal); dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]; cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities"); plot(cities); my.identify(cities); . . . works fine, though you'll need to work on details for error handling and vagaries of overlay

Comment: I think the mole's in the class of `data`. Have you tried stepping through the code by calling `debug(my.identify)` or inserting a `browser()` call somewhere in your function?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. `overlay` is deprecated and `over` should be used instead. The catch is that all objects should be `Spatial*`.

```
xy <- data.frame(x = runif(40, min = -200, max = 200),
    y = runif(40, min = -200, max = 200))
plot(xy)
my.identify <- function(data) {
    # allows you to create a polygon by clicking on map 
    region = locator(type = "o")  
    n = length(region$x)
    p = Polygon(cbind(region$x, region$y)[c(1:n,1),])
    ps = Polygons(list(p), ID="region")
    sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

    # returns all data that overlaps new polygon sps
    a=data[!is.na(over(SpatialPoints(data),sps)),]
    return(a)
}
ident <- my.identify(xy)
points(ident, pch = 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to the package in your function:

```
 my.identify <- function(data)
 {
      require('sp')  ## Call to load the sp package for use in stand alone function
      # allows you to create a polygon by clicking on map
      region = locator(type = "o")
      n = length(region$x)
      p = Polygon(cbind(region$x, region$y)[c(1:n,1),])
      ps = Polygons(list(p), ID="region")
      sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))


      # returns all data that overlaps new polygon sps
      a=data[!is.na(overlay(data,sps)),]

      return(a)
 }
```

Comment: Do you think it would come all the way down to overlay if `sp` wasn't loaded? `Polygon`, `Polygons` and `SpatialPolygons` are all `sp` methods...